# A word for making an event more likely or less likely

Tags: single-word-requests

In discussions of probability we often find ourselves saying that we can make an event more likely or less likely. It feels wordy, like there should be a single word for that. I don't mean "preclude" or "necessitate." I mean a change of probability that doesn't reach 0% or 100%. For example, we might say:

> If we increase the sample size, we [decrease the probability of] certain kinds of error.
>   If we decrease the sample size, we [increase the probability of] certain kinds of error.

What goes in that bracketed space? Not "rarify," which means something else; and not "preclude," which we can never seem to accomplish.

Comment: So you want a word for "the alteration of probability"? Or do you want one that specifies whether it is a decrease or it is an increase in probability?

Comment: "If we increase the sample size, we [decrease the probability of] certain kinds of statistical error."

Comment: Based on what you say in your question, this is simply "altering the probability",  and many synonyms to "alter" would work as well.

Comment: Perhaps "inhibit".

Comment: If we increase the sample size, we reduce statistical error through smoothening.

Comment: Are you looking something like **unlikelihood, improbable?** But doesn't fit in the sentence...

Comment: I vote to close as it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Canis Lupus Can you help me understand why your remark is not silly? It's unclear what I'm asking? Are there not boatloads of requests on this site exactly like this one in all important respects? Your first suggestion "Altering the probability of" is not one word; it's the same number of words I used in the original bracketed expression. And "If we increase the sample size we ALTER certain kinds of errors" doesn't even mean the same thing. Do you sometimes worry about your quickness to vote to close as it's unclear that you even read twice the question you're condemning?

Comment: Yes, I will. The fact that after a few hours your have received multiple divergent answers is the first clue. The second clue is that you have not provided any feedback that would help bring those answers into focus on what you are requesting. Specific to your question, do you want something that describes "*more less* likely or less likely" (from your title), "more or less likely" (from your question), or "less likely" (from your example)? If you want to get a good answer, sometimes you will have to tend to your question or it will wither.

Comment: @Canis Lupus As to the first clue, should these questions have been closed on grounds of multiple divergent answers? I'm looking for an idiom to describe improvement. “As true as I’m riding this bicycle”

Comment: @Canis Lupus As to the second clue, is the repeated word not a trivial, obvious error, a typo which is flimsy reed on which to hang your vote to close? Would it not be more natural to just point out or correct the typo?

Comment: @Canis Lupus So it’s funny. My good friend Mari-Lou A was telling me that despite all appearances, you are actually being consistent and constructive, and I only need to ask to find out why you vote to close. So I’m asking. Do you vote to close whenever a question contains a typo and receives six different answers, where the author does not provide any feedback for “a few hours”? And thus you should actually have voted to close dozens of other recent questions that meet that description, but you just didn’t get to it yet?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A See previous comment.

Comment: Incidentally, I just somehow happened upon my 4.5-yr-old question here, and the responses that now occur to me are (for increasing the probability of error) "promoting" or perhaps "magnifying" error and (for decreasing the probability) "retarding," "discouraging" or "mitigating" error.  And what's more, I have no more sympathy for @Canis Lupus than in March 2017.

Comment: Note that when you do something serious like change the sample size, you're **not** making an event more probable. You're designing a different event that has a different probability. You're changing the event, not its probability.

Comment: @John Lawler Of course we don't change the probability of the events that we were originally trying to predict, such the the outcome of an election. But I stand by what I said: if we increase the sample size, we decrease the probability of certain kinds of error; and that error is the "event" which we make less probable. I don't know exactly what it means to say (as you do) that you're "designing a different event that has a different probability."

Comment: It means that an experiment with N independent inputs is a different experiment from one with M (<> N) inputs, and one can expect it to deliver different results. It is probable that some of the effects are statistically more or less useful because of this, but they're about details that occur in both experiments and are therefore commensurable..

Answer (score 4):

The OED actually contains words for this:

> ### **disprobabilize, *v.***
>
> *rare*
>   *trans.* To deprive of probability, render improbable.
>
> ### probabilize, *v.*
>
> *trans.* To make probable or likely.
>
> ### **probabilify, *v.***
>
> *Philos.*
>   *trans.* To make probable, give probability to.

("disprobabilize, v.", "probabilize, v.", & "probabilify, v." *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, December 2016.)

Only the first is marked as rare(!), and the latter two (along with alternate spelling *probablize*) have all been updated with attestations into the 21st century.

So, for your example, you theoretically could say:

> If we increase the sample size, we **disprobabilize** certain kinds of error. If we decrease the sample size, we **probabilify/probabilize** certain kinds of error.

To my ear, however, they all sound goofy enough to probablize you sounding like you made them up on the spot and disprobabilize a serious reception. The fact that such unwieldy words needed to be coined also probabilifies the absence of better alternatives.

Comment: I must say that this is my favorite response so far, for (and despite) all the reasons you give. But I'm afraid these words would probabilify a lot of giggling and confusion in class.

Comment: @Chaim I completely agree. I hadn't heard of any of these until I went looking for an answer to your question, but now I am thinking I might occasionally sprinkle these in conversation and in my own classes, just for the pleasure of their "mouth feel"...and being able to follow up with "It's in the OED! Look it up!"

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is [**mitigate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mitigate)

> Make (something bad) less severe, serious, or painful.

This doesn't apply in the general case of reducing probability, but when you're talking specifically about an adverse condition, reducing its probability also tends to reduce its severity, and I think I've seen the word used in contexts like your example.

Answer (score 3):

> If we increase the sample size, we **disfavor** certain kinds of
> error. If we decrease the sample size, we **favor** certain kinds of
> error.

---

> For example, in the case of the Ising model, if we consider two
> neighboring variables, *X, Y,* the local function will **favor (higher
> probabilities)** configurations in which *X = Y* and will **disfavor
> (lower probabilities)** configurations in which *X ≠ Y*.
> [Luis Sucar;
> *Probabilistic Graphical Models*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Probabilistic_Graphical_Models/m8kQEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=disfavor%20decrease%20the%20probability%20of&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> With this information, they could see which sorts of triadic
> configurations seemed to be **favored (present above chance)** or
> **disfavored (present below chance)**.
> [John Levi Martin; *Thinking Through Statistics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thinking_Through_Statistics/dXllDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=favored%20or%20disfavored%20by%20chance&pg=PA262&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> The universe does not carry a memory of past results that will **favor
> or disfavor** future outcomes.
> [S. Martinez-Conde et al.; *Sleights of
> Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sleights_of_Mind/3p8mb-BzUKwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=favor%20or%20disfavor%20the%20probability&pg=PT211&printsec=frontcover)  (2011)

> This fact **disfavors** the possibility that genetic personality
> differences are maintained by a mutation selection hypothesis.
> [David
> Buss and Patricia Hawley; *The Evolution of Personality and Individual
> Differences*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Evolution_of_Personality_and_Individ/N2xnDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=disfavors%20that%20possibility&pg=PA428&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> They see the pattern as a "historical marker," something that
> **disfavors** chance resemblance, is persistent in language families, not implied by typological universals, and so on.
> [Lyle Campbell;
> *American Indian Languages*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Indian_Languages/i3g8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=disfavors%20the%20chances&pg=PA250&printsec=frontcover) (1997)

> Suppose intelligence is asked to estimate the comparative merits of
> two hypotheses—one of imminent war, the other of no imminent war. The
> estimate is to be expressed in terms of the odds **favoring or
> disfavoring** the war hypothesis.
> [H. Bradford Westerfield; *Inside
> CIA's Private World*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Inside_CIA_s_Private_World/6jfi0WTJ9tcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=disfavoring%20the%20chances&pg=PA256&printsec=frontcover) (1997)

> Both parts of the dichotomy **disfavor** her success in school and
> society. One part of the dichotomy provides genetic reasons for her
> failure; the other provides sociocultural ones.
> [Richard Meyer;
> *Official Portrais and Unofficial Conterportraits of 'At Risk' Students*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Official_Portraits_and_Unofficial_Counte/obuNAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=disfavor%20success&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> Domestic conditions **favoring or disfavoring** successful operation
> of incentives in the recipient state are likewise critically important
> considerations for policymakers.
> [William Long; *Economic Incentives
> and Bilateral Cooperation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Economic_Incentives_and_Bilateral_Cooper/QG9R2otVsSoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=favoring%20or%20disfavoring%20success&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover) (1996)

Comment: Do any dictionaries consider these senses idiomatic enough to list?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I haven't found even one, including online. I'll look for some examples of this use outside the sciences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I forgot about Sven Yargs' dictionary find in [Do dictionaries disfavor "disfavor"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586805/do-dictionaries-disfavor-disfavor)

Answer (score 2):

> If we increase the sample size, we **militate against** certain kinds
>   of error.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/militate-against-sth):

> militate against sthg:  to make something less likely to happen or succeed

Answer (score 0):

What about [**reduce**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reduce)? The Oxford Dictionary defines it as:

> 1. Make smaller or less in amount, degree, or size.

If we want to be technical (of course we do) it doesn't explicitly carry the implication that it's *less probable*, just that it *happens less*, but this distinction is commonly glossed over.

Answer (score 0):

"If we increase the sample size, we **minimise** (*reduce to the smallest possible amount, extent, or degree, OED*) certain kinds of error.

Answer (score 0):

If we increase the sample size, we **avert the occurrence** certain kinds of error.

> avert the occurrence:  to keep from happening; prevent [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/avert)

Comment: This would normally be understood that to imply that the probability is reduced to zero, while the OP is looking for a word that stands for reducing the probability somewhat, but not all the way to zero.

Answer (score 0):

**conducive** – making a certain situation or outcome likely or possible.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conducive#English):

> **conducive** (*comparative* more conducive, *superlative* most conducive)
>
> 1. Tending to contribute to, encourage, or bring about some result.
>
>    *A small, dark kitchen is not **conducive** to elaborate cooking.*

Comment: You should include the source of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

From the industrial food safety sector, regulatory agencies in the domestic US favor vernacular terms such as follows in policy and guidance documents:

- Control
- Reduce
- Mitigate

These are additionally associated with the following mechanisms, and prefixed by "critical" where compliance is mandatory or otherwise vital:

- Limits
- Parameters
- Control Points

Lastly, there is an explicit expectation for quantification of all analyses conducted when determining the necessity for controls to be implemented at any particular process flow point for the mitigation of potential hazards.  As such, the industry typically defines hazard **risks** as the arithmetic product of the **likelihood** (of occurrence) and the **severity** (of ramifications);  assigning values that are plotted into a two-dimensional chart then enables the qualitative assignment of risk categories utilizing terminology such as "high risk", "low risk", etc., given the expectation that these are clearly defined in policy documentation.

Due to the nature of the industry, there's an obvious skew in favor of only one direction of influence for risk-based — i.e., **preventative** — controls.  For data collection purposes, I've seen the use of terms such as **innoculate** when referencing the *intentional introduction* of, e.g., microbiological agents or contaminants.