# Do dictionaries disfavor "disfavor"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

A question on ELU asked for [A word for making an event more likely or less likely](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376421/a-word-for-making-an-event-more-likely-or-less-likely/586673#586673) and I proposed the verb pair *favor/disfavor* in an answer, with these examples:

> For example, in the case of the Ising model, if we consider two
> neighboring variables, *X, Y,* the local function will **favor (higher
> probabilities)** configurations in which *X = Y* and will **disfavor
> (lower probabilities)** configurations in which *X ≠ Y*. [Luis Sucar;
> *Probabilistic Graphical Models*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376421/a-word-for-making-an-event-more-likely-or-less-likely/586673#586673) (2020)

> The universe does not carry a memory of past results that will **favor
> or disfavor** future outcomes. [S. Martinez-Conde et al.; *Sleights of
> Mind*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/favor)  (2011)

---

There is no problem finding a dictionary definition for this sense of the verb **favor**:

> Work to the advantage of.
>
> *Natural selection has **favored** bats* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/favor)

> Of a circumstance, fact, etc.: To lend confirmation or support to (a
> belief, doctrine, rarely, a person); to point in the direction of.
>
> 1887   C. C. Abbott *Waste-land Wanderings* ii. 22   Every indication
> **favored** rain. (OED)

However, I was surprised when I couldn't find an opposite definition for the verb *disfavor*, such as *work to the disadvantage of* or *weaken confirmation or support*. For example, the *sole* definitions in these three dictionaries are:

**disfavor** (v.)

> To regard or treat with the reverse of favour or good will; to
> discountenance; to treat with disapprobation. (OED)

> Regard or treat (someone or something) with disfavor. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/Regard)

> To withhold or withdraw favor from [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disfavor)

Are there conditions or constraints (e.g. register) on using *disfavor* in the "neutral" sense of making something less probably or saying something is less likely, i.e. *without* denoting disapproval as in the above and following examples?

> This fact **disfavors** the possibility that genetic personality
> differences are maintained by a mutation selection hypothesis. [D.
> Buss et al.; *The Evolution of Personality and Individual
> Differences*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Evolution_of_Personality_and_Individ/N2xnDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22disfavors%20the%20possibility%22&pg=PA428&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Such bias **favors** the finding of positive associations and **disfavors**
> the possibility that significant associations do not exist. But
> despite such inherent bias, the observed effects were small. [*H.R.
> 1633, the Farm Dust Regulation Prevention Act of 2011*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/H_R_1633_the_Farm_Dust_Regulation_Preven/0s5FAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22disfavors%20the%20possibility%22&pg=PA164&printsec=frontcover)

> There is, therefore a well defined line which limits the extent to
> which the general government can act as a moral person, and regulate
> its powers so as to **favor or disfavor** particular acts of
> individuals in the States. [James Carter; *Cases Adjudged in the
> Supreme Court*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/United_States_Reports/4EtQdmXtGT4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20favor%20or%20disfavor%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover) (1891)

Is this meaning of *disfavor* so rare that it doesn't merit a dictionary definition?

Comment: Given OED's latest citation is 1895 and it was last comprehensively updated in 1896, it's likely that its entry is now incomplete.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Editorial disfavor perhaps? :-) The print *New Oxford American* is no better. OK, one down, many to go.

Comment: Dictionaries other than OED probably don't dedicate much space to paronyms which are far less idiomatic than the prototype. [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=favor%2Cdisfavor&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfavor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisfavor%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfavor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisfavor%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that's much too high a bar. See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=favor+or+disfavor%2C+hit+or+miss%2C+honor+or+dishonor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfavor%20or%20disfavor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20or%20miss%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chonor%20or%20dishonor%3B%2Cc0) instead

Comment: But dictionary usage panels look at actual overall currency in their research, not the odd selected phrase..

Comment: I  hesitated before posting my answer to the other ELU question I cited at the top, because, although I could find examples to back up *disfavor*, I could find no definition to cite.

Comment: The answer is going to be 'Although it is logical that this sense of _disfavo[u]r_ should exist, and the odd example can be found in creditable writing, the usage must be seen as very rare, so much so that most dictionaries do not list it. It should be used, if at all, with care.' IMO.

Comment: Are you asking **whether** dictionaries disfavour it (which you seem to have already answered in the question itself) or **why** they disfavour it?

Comment: @jsw29 I'm interested in information/views on this sense of the verb, which appears to be relatively new, although the verb itself is much older. It's just a hunch, but I think this could be more oversight than deliberate exclusion. IMO this sense is common enough to warrant inclusion. Would you hesitate to use it with this meaning? I've added "Is this meaning of *disfavor* so rare that it doesn't merit a dictionary definition?" to the question.

Comment: ... You'll have to get in touch with the individual editorial boards to get an answer to that. All others can do is refer to usual practice.

Comment: It can often take a while for a new sense of a word to make it into dictionaries. Lexicographers give more priority to adding new words than minor variations in definitions of existing words.

Comment: General dictionaries are often bad (or at least erratic) for technical meanings, and this sounds like a technical sense from computer science/mathematics/engineering. If it's used in textbooks or similar sources, it's probably fine.

Comment: @StuartF I would say that writers in computer science/mathematics/engineering are often bad (or at least erratic) in their use of English.

Answer (score 2):

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* fifth edition (2011) seems to be coming around to acknowledging the newer general sense of *disfavor* that you ask about:

> **disfavor** ... *tr.v.* ... **1.** To view or treat with dislike or disapproval. **2.** To slow down or otherwise reduce the success of (a chemical process or pathway): *conditions that disfavor the growth of a pathogen*.

Although definition 2 doesn't express precisely the sense (or senses) of *disfavor* that the examples you cite call for, it's at least in the vicinity. Perhaps most importantly, definition 2 provides a foothold for nonspecialists and word popularizers to use in transferring what was (and perhaps still is primarily) a technical term applicable to chemistry or medicine to less technical settings—a critical step in achieving mainstream blunting, broadening, and subsequent adoption of the previously specialized meaning.

Notably, previous editions of *AHDEL*, including the fourth edition (2000) list only definition 1 of *disfavor* as a verb. As Johnny Cash might say of definition 2, "I see that meanin' comin'; it's rollin' 'round the bend..."

Comment: Good find! That is the first dictionary mention of something akin to *likelihood*.